# What happened to dconf/Nautilus "show-advanced-permissions" in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, permissions, dconf

When using Nautilus and right-clicking on a file > Properties, user is presented with a permissions tab. The default UI for this permissions tab is horribly difficult to understand and calibrate and lacks any sort of user-friendliness. Accordingly, I need Nautilus to display the alternate view: what has always been called "advanced-permissions" view. Here is what the "advanced-permissions" look like:
[image]

using dconf Editor I have always been able to go to setting `dconf-editor > org > gnome > nautilus > preferences > show-advanced-permissions` and change the appearance of the permissions to this "advanced" presentation which makes the permissions much easier to understand and calibrate.

So how do I get Nautilus to display what has always been called "show-advanced-permissions"? Why is this setting missing from 13.04? How do I get it back?

Comment: A functional problem with not having "advanced permissions" view is that there is no GUI way of giving only the file Owner Execute-capability. Without the "advanced permissions" view, setting Execute on a file necessarily means giving Execute-power to 1)Owner, 2)Group, and 3)Others--something that is not only frustrating but also a security risk. With "advanced permissions" view, Execute can be assigned to only the 1)Owner.

Answer (score 2):

The advanced permissions mode in Nautilus was removed from August 2012.

> **Remove advanced permissions**
>
> This mode is worse than useless because it is impossible to find,
> it complicates the ongoing maintanence of the dialog, and if there
> is important configuration in it we should be offering it by default
> without a special hidden mode.

Source: [index : nautilus - Commit message: Remove advanced permissions](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=87cfa404d845cbd59b7bf5c95931aa930dbe3d15)

Comment: Is there any chance it will be back?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work on 13.04 but try this:

While still shown in gconf nautilus, settings are now handled through dconf. Install dconf-tools using `sudo apt-get isntall dconf-tools` on a terminal, then open `dconf-editor` & browse to **org > gnome > nautilus > preferences**

Or use `gsettings` as:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-advanced-permissions true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work with Ubuntu 14.04.