# GUI file permissions box

Tags: 14.04, permissions

I moved some pictures from my phone (cyanogen) to my laptop a few weeks ago.  Today, I noticed that the execute flag was set for all the pictures when I ran "ls -l" in the directory.  The funny thing is that, when I right click any picture and go to "permissions", the box that says "Allow executing file as program" is not checked, nor is it empty - instead it has a dash, like "-".  What does the dash mean, and why is it that its only an option for these pictures, for any other file, I only have two options, the "check" and empty.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you look at such a file with ll or chmod and see what permissions it shows?

Comment: Doesn’t it mean using a file system without permission support like FAT or NTFS? In my case, the permissions contain `x` in textual representation (`ls`) and are grayed out in the properties in GUI (Xubuntu).

Comment: @Melebius No, Thunar (default file-manager for Xubuntu) does not show execute permissions in the GUI in any way, Nautilus is different.

Comment: I don't know who down-voted your question, in my eyes it is a valid question, but lags some information. To avoid down-votes you should add a little bit more information, for example, which version and flavour of Ubuntu and which file-manager you use. You may also add the terminal output when you run `ls -l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nautilus simplifies the display of the execute permissions in the GUI.

The execute bit can be set for

1. Owner
2. Group
3. World

If the execute bit is set for none of them (`-rw-rw-rw-`), Nautilus displays an empty check-box.

If the execute bit is set for all of them (`-rwxrwxrwx`),Nautilus diplays a check-mark in the check-box.

If the execute bit is set, but not for all of them (`-rwxrwxrw-`), Nautilus displays  a dash in the check box.

Enabling/Disabling the execute permissions using the checkbox will set/remove the execute permissions for all users (owner, group and world), you cant set/remove the execute permissions in any other way, for example remove execute permission only for the owner of the file. to do that you will have to use the `chmod`-command in the terminal.

In former times there was a possibility to switch to an `advanced-permissions`-tab, but this has been removed a couple of years ago.
[What happened to dconf/Nautilus "show-advanced-permissions" in 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310147/what-happened-to-dconf-nautilus-show-advanced-permissions-in-13-04) , take a look at this to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks!  This was really helpful! (sorry it took me a while - I forgot my laptop before a trip :( )